# Deleted the default user, how to get it back

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11, access-rights

I accidentally deleted the default user. It does not work in other add-ons connected to it. Payroll, purchase, fingerprint scanner etc. Will I correct the database if I create user information that I deleted? Or how to solve it with other methods.
Thank you

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 84, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 68, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: ('ir.model.data', <function IrModelData.xmlid_lookup at 0x7f11b2540ea0>, 'base.default_user')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 650, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 692, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 342, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 335, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 936, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 935, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 923, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base_setup/models/res_config_settings.py", line 76, in open_default_user
    action['res_id'] = self.env.ref('base.default_user').id
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 793, in ref
    return self['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_object(xml_id, raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1339, in xmlid_to_object
    t = self.xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(xmlid, raise_if_not_found)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1323, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
    return self.xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]
  File "<decorator-gen-24>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 89, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1312, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: base.default_user
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update to `base` module or create the user directly in `Technical -> Sequences & Identifiers -> External Identifiers`

You can also create the deleted user using an XML data file:

```
<record id="base.default_user" model="res.users">
    <field name="name">Default User Template</field>
    <field name="login">default</field>
    <field name="active" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your modules then it will again created.